# Blank Lightning Record Page "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app."

Tags: lightning-record-page

I have created a new Lightning Record Page (it is completely blank, no components/items anything have been added) and assigned it to a custom profile I've created.

When I attempt to navigate to the page on the object I get a message:

> This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile
>   app.

The user has "View All" access to the object in question `InsurancePolicy` in the Financial Services Cloud application.

The page is visible when running as a System Administrator? What else could be blocking access to this blank Lightning Record Page? How should I debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the solution to this - I believe the API Version for the Lightning Record page was set too low for the `InsurancePolicy` object which was introduced in API V46 or V47.